# CouchDB exits when querying a view

Tags: couchdb

When I access `/mydatabase/_design/assets/_view/all` I'm getting the following error:

> "{"error":"EXIT","reason":"{function_clause,\n    [{couch_httpd,handle_db_request,\n         [{mochiweb_request, ..."

This is my view document:

```js
{
  "_id": "_design\/assets",
  "_rev": "4243492989",
  "language": "javascript",
  "views": {
    "all": {
      "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'asset') { emit(doc.name, doc); }}"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Kristian, your _id is fine.  It looks like the error I saw when I used a query that didn't match the API.  The view URLs [changed in version 0.9](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Breaking_changes#line-56).  You probably want to upgrade to the new version of CouchDB anyway.

See also this question: [CouchDB views erroring out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718039)